# Version name and code from files with gradle plugin 3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

My android build is set to use a `versionName` and `versionCode` from a file in release mode. They are set to static values when not creating a release build to keep incremental builds working.

The relevant parts of the gradle file are:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // SNIP...
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            variant.versionCode = file('version-code.txt').text as int
            variant.versionName = file('version.txt').text
        }
    }

    // SNIP ...
}
```

Example contents of the version files could be:

- **`version.txt`**:  `0.7`
- **`version-code.txt`**: `7`

This was done by following the [Use static build config values with your debug build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html#use_static_build_properties) section in the recommended guidelines for keeping incremental builds working.

> For example, using dynamic version codes, version names, resources, or any other build logic that changes the manifest file requires a full APK build every time you want to run a change—even though the actual change might otherwise require only a hot swap. **If your build configuration requires such dynamic properties, then isolate them to your release build variants and keep the values static for your debug builds, as shown in the build.gradle file below.**

However, we've found this has broken since upgrading to version 3 of the gradle plugin this no longer works. The [Modifying variant outputs at build time may not work](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output) section of the gradle plugin 3.0.0 migration guide says:

> **Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the new plugin.** It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during build time, as shown below:
>
> **However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing outputFile objects no longer work.** That's because variant-specific tasks are no longer created during the configuration stage. This results in the plugin not knowing all of its outputs up front, but it also means faster configuration times.

There doesn't seem to be any alternative recommended in the migration guide. Is there another way this can be achieved?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the answer from @nhoxbypass, changing my gradle file to contain following got things working again:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            output.setVersionNameOverride(file('version.txt').text)
            output.setVersionCodeOverride(file('version-code.txt').text as int)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_api) **still works** for simple tasks, such as changing the APK name during build time (at least worked for my project). However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing `outputFile` objects no longer work.

But if you need to try a workaround there is one existing before the 3.0 release, if anybody is looking for a solution, you can use:

```
output.setVersionCodeOverride(Integer.parseInt(buildTimeSmall()))
```

See: [Unable to change project versionCode for different build types](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63785806#comment6)